# SQL Counting results from a specific magazine within a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Bon_ID  Price_Articol   Store_Id
2       35.99           1300
2       55.99           1300
2       5.99            1300
3       75.99           1200
3       35.99           1200
3       25.06           1200
3       30.02           1200
4       15.99           1400
4       85.99           1400
4       95.29           1400
4       55.21           1400
4       78.34           1400
4       76.54           1400
5       21.02           1500
5       76.99           1500
5       35.99           1500
6       8.99            1300
6       12.99           1300
6       34.99           1300
6       31.99           1300
6       32.99           1300
6       99.99           1300
7       2.33            1300
7       1.33            1300
7       4.33            1300
7       6.33            1300
10      2.99            1300
11      4.99            1300
11      5.99            1300
```

I have the following table and I need to see how many `bon_ids` do I have on the store that is in a certain price range, I tried the following query but it returns only 1 from `COUNTBON` and on the 1300 `Store_Id` it should be 3.

```
WITH MyCTE AS (
  SELECT
    Store_ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Bon_ID) AS COUNTBON,
    CASE 
      WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) < 50 THEN '0-49.99' 
      WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) BETWEEN 50 AND 99.99 THEN '50-99.99'
      WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) BETWEEN 100 AND 149.99 THEN '100-149.99'
      WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) > 149.99 THEN 'MORE THAN 150'
      ELSE NULL
    END AS SUM_BON
  FROM Bons
  GROUP BY Bon_ID, Store_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
GROUP BY SUM_BON, COUNTBON, Store_ID
ORDER BY Store_ID ASC
```

And returns:

```
1200    1   MORE THAN 150
1300    1   0-49.99
1300    1   50-99.99
1300    1   MORE THAN 150
1400    1   MORE THAN 150
1500    1   100-149.99
```

Instead of:

```
1200    1   MORE THAN 150
1300    3   0-49.99
1300    1   50-99.99
1300    1   MORE THAN 150
1400    1   MORE THAN 150
1500    1   100-149.99
```

Answer (score 0):

> i need to see how many bon_ids do i have on the store that is in a certain price range

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT Store_ID,
       (CASE WHEN Price_Articol < 50 THEN '0-49.99' 
             WHEN Price_Articol < 100 THEN '50-99.99'
             WHEN Price_Articol < 150 THEN '100-149.99'
             WHEN Price_Articol >= 150 THEN 'MORE THAN 150'
             ELSE NULL
        END) as price_group,       
       COUNT(DISTINCT Bon_ID) AS COUNTBON
FROM Bons
GROUP BY Store_ID,
         (CASE WHEN Price_Articol < 50 THEN '0-49.99' 
               WHEN Price_Articol < 100 THEN '50-99.99'
               WHEN Price_Articol < 150 THEN '100-149.99'
               WHEN Price_Articol >= 150 THEN 'MORE THAN 150'
               ELSE NULL
          END);
```

If you don't like repeating the `CASE` expression, you can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT b.Store_ID, v.price_group,       
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.Bon_ID) AS COUNTBON
FROM Bons b CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN b.Price_Articol < 50 THEN '0-49.99' 
                   WHEN b.Price_Articol < 100 THEN '50-99.99'
                   WHEN b.Price_Articol < 150 THEN '100-149.99'
                   WHEN b.Price_Articol >= 150 THEN 'MORE THAN 150'
              END)
     ) v(price_group)
GROUP BY b.Store_ID, v.pricegroup
ORDER BY b.Store_ID, MIN(Price_Articol);
```

EDIT:

You may want the *sum* of the prices.  If so:

```
SELECT b.Store_ID, b.price_group,       
       COUNT(*) AS COUNTBON
FROM (SELECT b.StoreId, b.Bon_ID,
             SUM(b.Price_Articol) as total_price,
             (CASE WHEN SUM(b.Price_Articol) < 50 THEN '0-49.99' 
                   WHEN SUM(b.Price_Articol) < 100 THEN '50-99.99'
                   WHEN SUM(b.Price_Articol) < 150 THEN '100-149.99'
                   WHEN SUM(b.Price_Articol) >= 150 THEN 'MORE THAN 150'
              END) as price_group
      FROM Bons b 
      GROUP BY b.Store_ID, b.Bon_ID
     ) b
GROUP BY b.Store_ID, b.price_group
ORDER BY b.Store_ID, MIN(total_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Your CTE is fine, you would just need to modify the outer query to remove `COUNTBON` from the non-aggregated columns, and `SUM()` it instead.

New query:

```
WITH MyCTE AS (
    SELECT
        Store_ID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Bon_ID) AS COUNTBON,
        CASE 
            WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) < 50 THEN '0-49.99' 
            WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) BETWEEN 50 AND 99.99 THEN '50-99.99'
            WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) BETWEEN 100 AND 149.99 THEN '100-149.99'
            WHEN SUM(Price_Articol) > 149.99 THEN 'MORE THAN 150'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS SUM_BON
    FROM Bons
    GROUP BY Bon_ID,Store_ID
)
SELECT Store_ID, SUM(COUNTBON) COUNTBON, SUM_BON
FROM MyCTE
GROUP BY SUM_BON, Store_ID
ORDER BY Store_ID ASC
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f993b81557fea437c66df8d1d108327)**:

```
Store_ID | COUNTBON | SUM_BON      
-------: | -------: | :------------
    1200 |        1 | MORE THAN 150
    1300 |        3 | 0-49.99      
    1300 |        1 | 50-99.99     
    1300 |        1 | MORE THAN 150
    1400 |        1 | MORE THAN 150
    1500 |        1 | 100-149.99
```